# How can I see the assembly code of an Android Application?

Tags: android, disassembly

I am running my android application on my phone and I would like to see the assembly code that it is running. Is there a way to do that?

EDIT: I want to see the instructions that will be generated when my device is running the application

Comment: You mean decompile the apk?

Comment: I don't think this is possible, at least I've never heard of anything like it. That would be a pretty impressive project

Comment: There is at least one Web-based APK decompiler that will give you source in a language called smali, which is based on the Dalvik bytecode.  There's also a program called apktools that says it produces Java code, but I haven't tried it.

Comment: No, I want to see the instructions that will be generated when my device is running the application

Answer (score 1):

Android code is translated into Dalvik bytecode, not assembly. There is a utility called *dexdump* inside the Android SDK that can be run on an APK to generate its Dalvik bytecode. It's located at /*sdkroot*/build-tools/*version*/dexdump.